# now.js - Object has no method, but in jquery click event work

Tags: javascript, node.js, nowjs-sockets

I have a simple nowjs code for client:

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    window.now = nowInitialize('http://xxx.yyy:6564');

    now.recvMsg = function(message){
        $j("body").append("<br>" + message);
    }

    $j("#send-button").click(function(){
        now.sendMsg("well done"); //## this work
    });
    now.sendMsg("aaaah"); //## this dont work
});
```

and code for server-side:

```
var server = require('http').createServer(function(req, res){});
server.listen(6564);

var nowjs = require("now");
var everyone = nowjs.initialize(server);

everyone.now.sendMsg = function(message){
   everyone.now.recvMsg(message);
};
```

And calling sendMsg (server side function) work when it is in click event function, but outside in ready event dont work. Why?

I have even tried things like:

```
setTimeout('now.sendMsg("aaaah")',1000);
```

still dont work.

Comment: i dont know what u mean, but I set it up: setTimeout('now.sendMsg("aaaah")',2000); and for 2 seconds work, but not for 1 sec. eh, maybe i do loop until now.sendMsg exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NowJS needs time to load itself and there is no time to do that between 2nd and 11th line of your code. When you call:

```
now.sendMsg("aaaah"); //## this dont work
```

NowJS is still not loaded and can't execute this piece of code. When you click on a button NowJS is fully loaded and operation - and can send the message. Add a callback function to make sure that the library is set before trying to use it.